# UWP Standard CMS Enveloped Encryption

Tags: java, c#, uwp, cryptography, bouncycastle

I need to implement AES Encryption Algorithm in Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) to encrypt my data in Windows Universal App (found reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382008(v=vs.85).aspx)). I have it implemented on Java using Bouncy Castle library using the following code(I need the same functionality in C# UWP):

```
private static final ASN1ObjectIdentifier CMS_ENCRYPTION_ALGO = CMSAlgorithm.AES256_CBC;
private byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] dataToBeEncrypted) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, CMSException {
    final KeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
    final KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    final PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    final SubjectKeyIdentifier subjectKeyIdentifier = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils().createSubjectKeyIdentifier(publicKey);
    final RecipientInfoGenerator recipientInfoGenerator = new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(subjectKeyIdentifier.getEncoded(), publicKey);
    final CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator generator = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    generator.addRecipientInfoGenerator(recipientInfoGenerator);

    final OutputEncryptor encryptor = new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMS_ENCRYPTION_ALGO).build();
    final CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(dataToBeEncrypted);
    final CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData = generator.generate(content, encryptor);

    return envelopedData.toASN1Structure().getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);
}
```

Now I have Referenced Bouncy Castle V 1.8.1 in my UWP App, but I found many differences (some libraries used in Java but not exist in Windows) and couldn't implement such functionality in C#.

So kindly either guide me to implement the same using native UWP Cryptography Library `Windows.Security.Cryptography` (Preferred),

Or tell me how can I implement same functionality using Bouncy Castle 1.8.1 in C# UWP app.

**Update:**

Based on the following diagram from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382008(v=vs.85).aspx), I understand that the required steps are:

1- Get the data and generate Symmetric Key to encrypt the data using algorithm AesCbcPkcs7.

2- Encrypt Symmetric Key using the public key

3- Generate Digitally enveloped message.

[image]

So I did the first two steps based on my understanding using the following c# code (Please correct me if I'm wrong) and I need help to do the third step:

```
public string EncryptAndEnvelope(string openText, string p_key)
{
    // Step 1 Get the data and generate Symmetric Key to encrypt the data using algorithm AesCbcPkcs7
    IBuffer cBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(32);
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
    CryptographicKey m_key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(cBuffer);
    IBuffer bufferMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(AsciiToString(StringToAscii(openText)), BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, bufferMsg, null);

    // Step 2 Encrypt Symmetric Key using the public key
    IBuffer publicKey = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(p_key);
    AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asym = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
    CryptographicKey ckey = asym.ImportPublicKey(publicKey, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo);
    IBuffer cbufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(ckey, cBuffer, null);
  
    // Step 3 Generate Digitally enveloped message
    // I need help here
}

private byte[] StringToAscii(string s)
    {
        byte[] retval = new byte[s.Length];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < s.Length; ++ix)
          {
            char ch = s[ix];
            if (ch <= 0x7f) retval[ix] = (byte)ch;
            else retval[ix] = (byte)'?';
          }
        return retval;
    }
    
private string AsciiToString(byte[] bytes)
{
    return string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b <= 0x7f ? (char)b : '?'));
}
```

> **Note**: While I was looking for solution, I've found that the answer is available using the library `System.Security.Cryptography`
> (**[but it is not supported in Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134710/5746504)**) and I'm pretty sure that
> the implementation is available using [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) (there are
> tons of documentation for Java **but unfortunately there is no
> documentation at all for C#**).

Comment: UPW has Cms support now (CmsAttachedSignature, CmsDetachedSignature) have you checked that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814759/sign-data-using-cms-based-format-in-uwp